# Create a table "ca" as a statement using values of another tables but while inserting new values, the values of "ca" doesn't change

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I want to calculate turnover like in new table called ca  '

```
create table ca   as (select sum(a.prixvente * c.qte)as ca , c.datec as datee  from article a , command c where a.ida = c.ida and c.datec
= c.datec group by c.datec  ) ;
```

I have tables article (`idarticle`, `priceBuying`, `priceSale`, `quantity`),
and table command have (`idarticle`, `quantity`, `dateSale`),
I want to calculate turnover automatically everyday and insert into ca , but the problem is when I insert new values into command the values of ca not updating
using oracle db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create table as select` creates a table and populates it with the data from the `select` at the time it was run.  There is nothing that would automatically update the table going forward.

You could certainly write code that would `insert` new data for subsequent days (and/or `update` older rows) and then schedule that code to run at a reasonable point in time (i.e. midnight or 2am or something).

My guess, however, is that you really want to create a view rather than a table.  A view is just a stored query so it would be re-run every time you queried the view.

```
create or replace view ca   
as 
select sum(a.prixvente * c.qte)as ca , 
       c.datec as datee  
  from article a , 
       commande c 
 where a.ida = c.ida 
   and c.datec = c.datec 
 group by c.datec
```

You could also potentially want to create a `materialized view` that was scheduled to automatically refresh on a particular schedule.

Comment: thank you , do you mean create a trigger can inserting data automatically into "ca" every day at 2am for example ? I will try this solution I think it might work . but about why i use table instead of view rather because if user change priceSale , The transaction number of the old sales will also change,
So I want to calculate the transaction number and store it in the table automatically after each day .

Comment: @GEEKMEHDISA - A trigger fires in response to a DML operation.  You can't have a trigger fire at 2am.  You could create a stored procedure that does an `insert` and use the `dbms_scheduler` package to schedule that procedure to run at 2am.